# SVN update in post-commit hook

Tags: svn, batch-file, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

I'm trying to write a post-commit hook for a VisualSVN server on MSWindows, that immediately after the commit updates the server's project. On the server side: when I'm commiting a revision the `svn up` command cannot be executed in the hook. On the client side I get the message `Transmiting file data.` and no further messages.

post-commit hook:

```
call C:\batch\_something_.cmd
call svn up D:\path\to\local\project       <--- it's freezing here
```

Thank You!

Comment: Updating a working copy should not be automatized. Consider what should the code do in the case of merge conflicts. Proper way is to send a notification to anyone who is interested in immediate updates, so that they can do the updates when they are ready.

Comment: @Dialecticus I guess he wants to update a WC with a website or something like this (e.g. for testing).

Comment: @bahrep that's even worse. SVN is not meant to be used as deployment tool. Use a proper deployment tool instead.

Comment: @Dialecticus I can partially agree, but it still works for testing of small project locally.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `call` here. Remove it!

Use

```
"C:\batch\_something_.cmd"
"<path-to-svn.exe>" update D:\path\to\local\project
exit 0
```

Comment: I tried and unfortunately this is NOT the source of my problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Btw. You need a `CALL` for a .bat or .cmd file, else it will not return

Answer (score 0):

Goto the visualsvn server -> select the repository -> properties-> Hooks ->Post commit hook

```
pushd D:\path\to\local\project
svn update --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username *** --password *** --no-auth-cache
```

Did you try to execute it manually and check what happened? Sometimes it might be due to the client certificate error.